# Remove the specific xml tag using shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I'm fairly new to this but, I need to remove a specific element from an xml file using shell scripting.
The file goes like this:

```
<b>
      <a>AB</a>
      <c>CD</c>
      <d>EF</d>
</b>
<b>
      <a>AB1</a>
      <c>CD2</c>
      <d>EF3</d>
</b>
```

After I run my script, the file should look like this:

```
<b>
      <a>AB1</a>
      <c>CD2</c>
      <d>EF3</d>
</b>
```

I've looked into sed with delete option but couldn't really figure out the exact script. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you might need to explain the requirement a bit more and give more more examples. To use your example you have a ``<b>`` tag at two levels and you are looking to remove the second occurrence of the tag? Or are you just looking to remove the last occurrence of the tag? Or just the last 5 lines from the file?

Comment: How is java involved into this?

Comment: I need to remove the specific <b> tag. i.e, the <b> tag that has <a>AB</a> <c>CD</c> ....... and so on. The <b> tag can be anywhere. It could be the second occurence or the last occurence. The occurence doesn't really matter

Comment: So your example ``<b>`` tag (and its ``AB|CD|EF`` content) is *exactly* what you want to remove from *any* file??

Comment: @Karthik Domada – Contrary to what you wrote in your comment, you did not remove _the <b> tag that has <a>AB</a> <c>CD</c> ....... and so on_ in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Power Shell Script :

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$bs = $doc.Descendants("B")

foreach($b in $bs)
{
    b.Remove
}
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: This will remove all the <b> tags, if i'm not wrong?

Comment: Yes.  From you sample posted how do you know which <b> tags should be removed?